# Как задать кастомный setter в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

сеттер вида:

```
public Object set$localname$ ($type$ $localname$) {
    this.$localname$ = $localname$;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Сеттер должен возвращать экземпляр класса? Больше не видно отличий от того сеттера, что создает  IDE по дефолту.

Comment: @pavlofff увидел в гайде по моддингу для майнкрафта. Мне показалось это интересным. Например класс `planet` : `planet1.setMass(300).setVelocity(3000).setEccentricity(1.3d);` То есть делать несколько сетов в одну строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При генерации сеттера, можно выбрать шаблон builder вместо default, а лучше всего использовать lombok

Answer (score 3):

При выборе автосоздания сеттера (*Code -> Generate -> Setter* или <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>) появляется окно создания сеттера:

[image: scrn]

Вы можете нажать на иконку трех точек, справа от строки с выбором шаблона  (*Template:*) и в появившемся мастере нажать на "плюс" слева вверху и задать собственный произвольный шаблон генерации сеттера.
Так же для генерации сеттера для [паттерна Builder](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) уже есть готовый шаблон - вы можете выбрать его в выпадающем списке (*Template*) шаблонов: *Builder*

Comment: Спасибо, работает